# django error:can't specify the download filename

Tags: python, django

```
def download(request):
    f = open("next_op.xls")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    response = HttpResponse(data, content_type = './application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="nextop.xls"'
    return response
```

When I use this code, I can download the file correctly, but the file name is invalid.  I get the file name "download", and I found the response header doesn't include the **Content-Disposition** after I download the file.

Comment: What filename do you get?..

Comment: I think `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="nextop.xls"'` should be changed to `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="next_op.xls"'`

Comment: i get the filename "download"  and i found the response header don't  include the 'Content-Disposition' after i download the file @Sayse

Comment: Inserted OP's clarification into the question.

Answer (score 0):

you may need this:

```
fd = open(file, 'rb')
return FileResponse(fd, as_attachment=True, filename='xxx')
```